# Swift: NaN output

Tags: swift

Below is some very basic code for your SO experts. I have two fields (weight and height) and a segmented control with two options. When the control is clicked, I fire an action to get the values of the weight and height fields. I then do a small amount of math and am looking to dump the result to another label field (result). Whenever entries are calculated the results field is populated with "NaN". Any ideas as to why? I'm sure it is in some formatting or conversion somewhere.

Edit: Updated to specify the issue.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var WeightNumberTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var HeightNumberTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CalculateType: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var results: UILabel!

    var weight = Float()
    var height = Float()
    var BMI = Float()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func newCalculation(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch CalculateType.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            let BMI = (weight * 703) / height;
            results.text = BMI.description;
        case 1:
            let BMI = weight / height;
            results.text = BMI.description;
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on purpose? Or did you accidentally click the margin in the gutter next to that line of code & set one (indicated by small blue arrow)? If you don't want a breakpoint, click it once to disable, or click & drag it away to delete it in a puff of smoke. Look into how to use breakpoints & the debugger to step through or continue code execution.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed that. Now I just get a non-number ("NaN") in the output. Any clues off hand as to what? I don't fully understand casting in Swift yet, so I'm sure it is somewhere in there.

Comment: Your 3 vars are all Type `Float`, but have no initial value. As rob mayoff says below - you're dividing 0/0. Instead of using `.description` you could try using String interpolation (e.g. `results.text = "\(BMI)"`) but I don't think that'd have a different result.

Answer (score 6):

The `weight` and `height` fields are initialized to 0. You never modify them. Dividing 0 / 0 in floating point returns NaN (not-a-number).

You probably want something like this:

```
    @IBAction func newCalculation(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        weight = Float(WeightNumberTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0
        height = Float(HeightNumberTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0
        switch CalculateType.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            let BMI = (weight * 703) / height;
            results.text = BMI.description;
        case 1:
            let BMI = weight / height;
            results.text = BMI.description;
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed didn't realize that I never actually assigned anything to the variables. Unreal. Anyhow, your code looks great and functional, however it throws an error for "String is not convertible to ()". Any idea why that would be? I'm assuming because the .Text is a string, but how would you go about fixing something like this or converting it?

Comment: Also note that "newCalculation" isn't called when the view is loaded, so if tab 0 is default, it won't work out the tab 0 selection until you switch to tab1 then back to tab0.. have `newCalculation(nil)` in the viewDidLoad: method to call it when it initially loads to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

if it's breaking at a "breakpoint" then somewhere in your code you'll have set one. This is a point in your code that the Xcode debugger stops (well pauses) for you to do various things to the code using the debugger etc...

You can see where a breakpoint is in one of several ways:

1) Using the "Breakpoint Navigator" which appears in the left-most pane of Xcode under a tab which appears like this:

[image]

2) By looking for breakpoints in the gutter of your code. In the actual code pane, where all your code is, you'll see just left of it a "gutter" which could appear in a number of ways depending how you've got Xcode set up... Mine appears as follows (with a breakpoint):

[image]

note) Where the arrow is pointing is where the breakpoint is. i.e. the highlighted bit in blue. You can enable and disable them by just clicking on them... If it's disabled, it'll appear "Greyed out" i.e. like this:

[image]

Finally, in regards to referring to the text field "filled in values" and the "unsegmented control action", you need to:

i) Textfield values:

```swift
// Somewhere in a code-block (i.e. a function)
let height = self.HeightNumberTextField.text

// Do some validation i.e. is it a number, is it greater than etc...
```

ii) Reference to the segmented control from the action:

```swift
// As you can see there's (sender: UISegmentedControl) which 
//     is the segmented control that you're clicking on so your 
//     switch statement should be..

switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex
```

sender (applies to all controls) is the control which performed the action i.e. in this case, the UISegmentedControl which you've tapped on. This is especially handy if you have several UISegmentedControls referring to one action.

Hope this helps!

*edit* Just something to add, I'd personally have "default values" on both of the textfields to be "0" so when the view loads, there's at least something there. Also I'd move the actual BMI calc to another function and refer to it from the action rather than work it out in the action.

Comment: Very precise and thorough answer to the original issues at hand. Thank you.